# Apply Face material(image texture) to IcosahedronGeometry thee.js

Tags: three.js

i am not able to apply different material on each face of IcosahedronGeometry.
here is my code.below code is working fine for boxgeometry.

```
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

var texture0 = textureLoader.load( 'google.png' );
...
var texture19 = textureLoader.load( 'google.png' );

var materials = [
   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture0 } ),
   ...
   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture19 } )
];
var faceMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
var globe = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(75,0);
var Ico = new THREE.Mesh(globe, faceMaterial);
Ico.rotation.z = 0.5;
scene.add(Ico);
```

also tried to set material index for each face with no luck.See below code.

```
var globe = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(75,0);        
    globe.materials =materials;
    for( var i = 0; i < globe.faces.length; i ++ ) {        
        globe.faces[i].materialIndex = i;

}
var Ico = new THREE.Mesh(globe, globe.materials);
```

can anybody point me to related example or any solution?

Thanks

Comment: See [this three.js example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials.html) and edit it to use `IcosahedronGeometry( 75, 0 );

Comment: thanks for comment.i can add different color or plane texture on every face but problem i am facing is, image texture is not showing properly on Icosahedron faces.For example IcosahedronGeometry( 75, 0 ) have 20 faces and i want different image on each face of Icosahedron.(as per my code above)

Comment: You need to learn about UVs. See http://threejs.org/examples/misc_uv_tests.html

Comment: thanks,Got it working.